# Does the Lawrence–Krammer representation provide a quantized action on the space of networks?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, network-theory

Let $\rho:B_n \rightarrow H_2(\overline{C_2 P_n})$ denote the Lawrence–Krammer representation of the braid group on $n$ symbols. The group $H_2(\overline{C_2 P_n})$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}[q,t]$-module of rank $\binom{n}{2}$. The braid group admits a surjective map to the symmetric group on $n$ symbols via “shrinking” or ignoring the braids, the “time” direction. There is an “unlabeling” action of $\Sigma_n$ on a complete (weighted) graph, or network, of dimension $\binom{n}{2}$.

**Q**: Is there a sense in which this L–K representation quantizes the unlabeling action on the moduli space of networks in the limit as $q \rightarrow 1$ and $t \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: I suppose one could check for starters if the characters agree in that limit?

Comment: Good idea. IIRC, the characters of the unlabeling action are characters of the symmetric group, Specht modules. In this case, it is the second symmetric power of the standard representation. In Young module notation, $(2,n-2)$, and is irreducible.